# Add urlImage 3 times to AdapterViewPager problem - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I supposed to get ImageDisplay from ArrayJson, it will hit API 3 times
this function will send urlimage 3 times

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++){send(UrlImage);}
```

**this works**

```
private void getViewYoyo(){
    String[] str = new String[3];
    adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity(), str);


    str[0]="https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2019/1-nasastessmis.jpg";
    str[1]="https://i.chzbgr.com/full/8803531264/hD42E57C6/";
    str[2]="https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2019/1-nasastessmis.jpg";
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPagerHot);
}
```

**But this doesn't work**

```
public void getHighlightMainActivity(int ReceivedDummyUrutan, int ReceivedTotalThread, int ReceivedDummyID, String ReceivedDummyTitle, String ReceivedDummyPublishTime, String ReceivedDummyImageOri, String ReceivedDummyShortDescription){
    String[] str = new String[ReceivedTotalThread];
    adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity(), str);
    if(ReceivedDummyUrutan==0)
        str[0]=ReceivedDummyImageOri;
    if(ReceivedDummyUrutan==1)
        str[1]=ReceivedDummyImageOri;
    if(ReceivedDummyUrutan==2)
        str[2]=ReceivedDummyImageOri;

    if(ReceivedDummyUrutan==ReceivedTotalThread-1) {
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPagerHot);
    }
}
```

This is adapterViewPager.java

```
public class AdapterViewPagerHot extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
/*private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.cat_mermaid_cartoon_grumpy_cat_94004_1280x720,R.drawable.catnrobot,R.drawable.kleptocats,R.drawable.magiccat,R.drawable.flyingcat};*/
public String image_url[];

public AdapterViewPagerHot(Context context, String[] list) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.image_url = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_url.length;
}

public void setUrls(String[] list){
    this.image_url = list;
}



@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}



public View vi;
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_viewpagerdisplay, null);

    final Context sContext = mContext;
    ImageView imageView = vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final ImageView ICONHotViewPagerSaving = vi.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotViewPagerSaving);
    /*imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);*/
    Glide.with(sContext).load(image_url[position]).into(imageView);


    vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(sContext, "Slide" + (position+1) + "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    final Boolean[] boollatestnewssaving = {false};
    ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (boollatestnewssaving[0] == true){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = false;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(boollatestnewssaving[0] == false) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = true;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(vi, 0);
    return vi;

}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);

}
```

}

What will happen with GetHighlight function is it will show the third image only, the first and second image was blank
I am not sure how to make it works like this

```
String test[]=new String[]{urlImageSend>>Image1, urlImageSend>Image2, urlImageSend>>Image3}
```

by hitting using for 3 times

Comment: Every time you are making new string[] so at last function call only third image URL was present

Comment: Hmm is there another way for me to fix that?

Comment: Use ArrayList it is better way then using String array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare one ArrayList which will hold the image URLs in your activity class like this

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now define one function which will insert the image URL's in the ArrayList

```
list.add(imageURL);
```

Now create your viewpager adapter and set the adapter

```
adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity(), list);
```

Make sure you change string to arraylist in the AdapterViewPagerHot class

Comment: if I declare String ImageUrl without using ImageAray[], @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_url[].length;
    } will become error

Comment: Just replace String with arraylist and return arraylist.size();

Comment: Use ArrayList and return ArrayList size in getCount() method